# undefined index al recibir datos de $_POST['mensajegeneral']

Tags: php

estoy haciendo un programa para hacer un correo. Este es mi código

```
<?php
include '../clases/Postmark.php';

ini_set('display_errors',1);

echo "hola";
if ($_GET['source2']=="enviar") {



$body ='<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="es"><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" /><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.jarboss.com/Bootstrap/v3/css/bootstrap.css"></head>';
$body.='<body style="padding-left:20px;">';
$body.='Se realizó una nueva cotización<br><br>';
$body.='<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs" style="text-align:right">'.$_POST['mensajegeneral'].'</div></div>';
// $body.='<div class="table-responsive"><table class="table table-bordered table-hover" style="width:95%;"><thead class="tUsuarios" style="background-color: #0066ff;color:white;"><th>Producto</th><th>Presentación</th><th>Existencia</th><th>UM</th><th>Cantidad solicitada</th><th>Precio sugerido</th></thead>';
// $body.='<tbody id="contenedorOrden">'.$tabla.'</tbody></table></div>';
$body.='<br>Speedee Servicio Automotriz<br>Tel. Oficina:+52 (81) 1306 9278 <br>E-mail: soporte@jarboss.com <br>www.speedee.com.mx</br>';
$body.='<small style="color:#CCC;"><br>Hola ¿como estás?.</small></body></html>';
$asunto ="Contacto";
echo $body;
//$server['mail'] = $arts->enviarMail($correo,$body,$asunto);
//$server['direccion']=$direccion;

    }

 ?>`
```

Comment: El ```$_POST['mensajegeneral']``` indica que estas recibiendo algun dato si no recibes nada te va a salir indefinido

Comment: Estas usando `$_GET` o `$_POST`?

Comment: @alanfcm estoy usando $_POST

Comment: en el apartado de solicitud del inspector no recibo nada, tampoco tengo idea de por qué @christian

Comment: Bueno con ```$_GET``` supongo lo haces para mostrar cuando alguien ingresa a esa página, pero si dices que utilizas ```$_POST``` deberías de comprobar que si se envía los datos y que la variable esté bien escrita ```$_POST['mensajegeneral']``` para comprobar esto al inicio pon un ```var_dump($_POST)```

Comment: @christian me sale un array (0) { }. Perdón si hago preguntas muy tontas pero es que aún no tengo muchos conocimientos de esto, especialmente en lo de enviar correos

Comment: Verifica que envíes los datos por el método POST

Answer (score 0):

Intenta lo que te han comentado, hacer un volcado (`var_dump`) de las variables `$_GET` y `$_POST`, también te puede resultar útil hacerlo a `$_REQUEST` y `$_SERVER`, en esta última variable vas a encontrar por ejemplo el tipo de petición.

No obstante, revisa el código del formulario, ¿especificaste `method="post"`? Puede que el formulario se esté enviando por una petición `GET`, por eso el error "`undefined index`" al intentar acceder a `$_POST['mensajegeneral']`. Eso o un error en el nombre de la variable.

Para que tu script funcione, el formulario debe ser algo así como:

```
<form action="/tuscript.php?source2=enviar" method="post">

    <label for="mensajegeneral">Mensaje</label>
    <textarea name="mensajegeneral"></textarea>

    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">

</form>
```